# Change friendly time format in Elgg

Tags: php, function, date-format, datetime-format, elgg

I use elgg 2.6.3.
I want to change the date time format of all events from duration time(from create date to now) to create date.
For example I want to change the "posted 1780 Days ago", to "posted on Dec 20, 2011".
How can I change this code for this issue? (this code return the date time format)

```
function elgg_get_friendly_time($time, $current_time = null) {

if (!$current_time) {
    $current_time = time();
}

// return a time string to short circuit normal time formatting
$params = array('time' => $time, 'current_time' => $current_time);
$result = elgg_trigger_plugin_hook('format', 'friendly:time', $params, null);
if ($result) {
    return $result;
}

$diff = abs((int)$current_time - (int)$time);

$minute = 60;
$hour = $minute * 60;
$day = $hour * 24;

if ($diff < $minute) {
    return elgg_echo("friendlytime:justnow");
}

if ($diff < $hour) {
    $granularity = ':minutes';
    $diff = round($diff / $minute);
} else if ($diff < $day) {
    $granularity = ':hours';
    $diff = round($diff / $hour);
} else {
    $granularity = ':days';
    $diff = round($diff / $day);
}

if ($diff == 0) {
    $diff = 1;
}

$future = ((int)$current_time - (int)$time < 0) ? ':future' : '';
$singular = ($diff == 1) ? ':singular' : '';

return elgg_echo("friendlytime{$future}{$granularity}{$singular}", array($diff));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask my question.
Just change this function as below (very simple and easy):

```
function elgg_get_friendly_time($time)
{
 return elgg_echo(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time));
}
```